# Finding a Dot Product without using np.dot or loops in Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dot-product

I need to write a function which:

1. Receives - two `numpy.array` objects
2. Returns - the floating-point dot product of the two input
   `numpy` arrays

**Not allowed to use:**

1. `numpy.dot()`
2. loops of any kind

Any suggestions?

Comment: This seems like a homework question. Why don't you share some code you've written so far?

The question is asking you to implement dot product without using a loop and without using np.dot. Look at some of the numpy functions and see if there's a way you can construct something that's equivalent to a dot product.

Comment: First you should read about and understand what a dot product really does to two vectors.  It's probably simpler than you think.

Comment: Have you considered reduce()?

Comment: @awiebe: There is no need for it (and using it would prevent you from benefiting from `numpy` at all). Dot product is just element-wise multiplication, then summing, and they're explicitly allowed to use `np.sum`, and multiplication is easy.

Comment: Someone just did your homework for you - https://stackoverflow.com/q/52889517/901925

Comment: When we talk of removing loops in `numpy`, we are actually moving them down a level, into compiled code.  The loops are still there, just hidden, and hopefully faster.  Element-wise multiplication of two vectors is just as much a loop as `dot`.  An exercise like this is more a test of your own knowledge of an inner product, than it is a test of being clever.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution makes use of recursion

```
import numpy as np

def multiplier (first_vector, second_vector, size, index, total):
    if index < size:
        addendum = first_vector[index]*second_vector[index]
        total = total + addendum
        index = index + 1
        # ongoing job
        if index < size:
            multiplier(first_vector, second_vector, size, index, total)
        # job done
        else:
            print("dot product = " + str(total))
    
def main():
    a = np.array([1.5, 2, 3.7])
    b = np.array([3, 4.3, 5])
    print(a, b)

    i = 0
    total_sum = 0

    # check needed if the arrays are not hardcoded
    if a.size == b.size:
        multiplier(a, b, a.size, i, total_sum)

    else:
        print("impossible dot product for arrays with different size")

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably considered cheating, but Python 3.5 [added a matrix multiply operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-465) that `numpy` uses to compute the dot product without actually calling `np.dot`:

```
>>> arr1 = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> arr2 = np.array([3,4,5])
>>> arr1 @ arr2
26
```

Problem solved!